# Get position of element with elastic scroll with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble with finding the distance of a div relative to the top of the window when elastic scroll is factored in. I'm using the usual `window.scrollY + element.getBoundingClientRect().top`, but that only gives 0 for an element positioned at the top of the body, even when the screen is elasticscrolled all the way up (so there is some distance from the top of the body to the top of the viewport). Is there a way of finding the actual distance from the top?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with elastic scroll, but couldn't you use CSS' snap scroll instead? Seems like the same thing and without the need for finding the distance...